# Magento CE 2.0 installation stops at about 90%

Tags: php, magento, mamp

This the first time I work with Magento, I tried to install Magento CE 2.0, But it's stick on 90%" :

[image]

I increase the max_execution_time as mentanyt [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_70pct.html) But not work !

I also increase it to 28000, no luck :(

Any suggestion please ..

(Mac OSx Capitan, MAMP Server, PHP 5.6.10, mysql 5.6.25)

Thanks in advance

Abdusalam

Comment: Off topic, this belongs in the Magento stackexchange community. http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Magento installation and administration questions belong over on magento.stackexchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, This is the solution :

Changes the below values in **php.ini** file to:

```
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = 1800
memory_limit = 1024M
```

Hope this help

Regards